# PyQT5 how two promoted classes share data

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have two classes whick one it plot widget and second is Menu item.
I want the menu item open a TXT file and send the data to Plot widget which will show it.

Main code

```
class MatplotlibWidget(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()

        loadUi("FHD_Ant_layout.ui",self)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 & Matplotlib Antenna GUI")
```

Widget Class

```
class XYPlotWidget(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, parent ):

        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
        
        vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        
        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.setLayout(vertical_layout)

    def update_graph(self , data):
            
        self.canvas.axes.clear()
        self.canvas.axes.plot(range(-int(len(data)/2),int(len(data)/2)), np.array(data)/max(data))
        self.canvas.axes.set_title('Cartesian Coordinate System')
        self.canvas.draw()
```

Menu Bar Class - From Function 'openTextFile' I need send the data to update_graph function.

```
class FileMenuWidget(QMenu):
    
    def __init__(self, parent):

        QMenu.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self.triggered.connect(lambda: self.openTextFile())

    def openTextFile(self):
      dataset=readfile(getTxtFileName())
      data = self.createGraphData(np.array([dataset['GAIN'] - x for x in  dataset['VERTICAL']]))
      return data #I need this data go to Plot class

    def createGraphData(data):
      max_index =np.argmax(data)
      graphData = np.concatenate((data[180-max_index:], data[:180-max_index]))
      return graphData
```

How I connect between those classes , the idea its important me to understand because I am absolutely will have this troubles again.

Comment: Is `FileMenuWidget` promoted in Designer as a menu of the menubar?

Comment: promoted to Menu

Comment: Then access it from the main class using its object name. Supposing it's called `myMenuWidget` in Designer, then it will be accessible through `self.myMenuWidget`. From there you can connect it to the functions you need.

Comment: Thank you ! it worked !